# How can I change the style of a .NET MAUI menu bar?

Tags: .net, menu, maui

I decided to try .NET Maui for an application I am working on at home.  I don't have much so far, just a page with a grid.  I added Content.MenuBarItems to the page, but for the life of me I can't find any information on how to style it.  Not on StackOverflow, Google, Bing or Bing CoPilot (AI is not there yet, it kept giving me solutions that wouldn't even compile).

My problem is that the menu bar is way too large, I don't want it to be animated, and I want to be able to control the font size and color.  The app is only windows/mac desktop, and I am aware that on Mac the menu will be a normal menu at the top of the screen that I can't style.  But I really don't like the default windows look.  For now, I'm using the sample menu in the documentation for Maui.  The code is below, not much to it.

```
<ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
    <MenuBarItem Text="File">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Exit" />
    </MenuBarItem>
    <MenuBarItem Text="Locations">
        <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Change Location">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Redmond, USA"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="London, UK" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Berlin, DE" />
        </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
        <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add Location"/>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit Location"/>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Remove Location" />
    </MenuBarItem>
    <MenuBarItem Text="View">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Refresh"/>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Change Theme" />
    </MenuBarItem>
</ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
```

[image: Large Menu Bar]

Comment: Sarah trust me. Build the menu from scratch.  Do the same for bottom tabs. The embedded controls are limited and very difficult even impossible to customize. Create your own controls by using the standard layouts provided. Create a new content page with all the functionality you want, and then inherit it to all of your pages. You can thank me later.

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas That’s exactly what I was afraid of.  I tried Maui out only to run into multiple things it doesn’t support well or at all out of the box.

Comment: I can understand your concerns. BUT if you build it from scratch then sky is the limit. Needs some effort at the beginning but the result will be awesome.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to customize window `MenuBarItems` fonts & styles , for more details, you can refer to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9837